# How to configure Facebook like button and LinkedIn share button

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, .net-4.0, linkedin-api

Can anyone tell me how to configure Facebook like button and LinkedIn share button on a website to like a particular link on the page. I don't want it to like the entire page but a link on a web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Facebook Like Button documentation, you can specify a ["URL to Like"](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Similarly with the LinkedIn [Share button](http://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share-plugin-generator), you can specify a URL.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedIn:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.

Facebook:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}
```

Source: **[FaceBook Share URL Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/357750474364812/)**.

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]